# Unix printing a banner page on every print job

Tags: unix, printing

I have a Data General server on unix that is printing a banner page on every print. I originally thought that the banner page was comming from the printer. As this is an HP printer, I used telnet to get to the jetadmin and then proceded to disable the banner page, but this did not solve the issue.

I then went into the sysadm program to see if the TCPIP printing was set to print a banner page on print jobs, but I did not see any options to print a banner page.

Any help or ideas on how to disable the banner page from printing in unix?

[Here is a banner page example print](https://i156.photobucket.com/albums/t12/jakester05/glbanner.jpg)

[image: Here is what prints out]

Comment: Please provide the flavour of UNIX, what kind of print queue, print queue definition details, exact printer type, etc., etc.

Comment: Bryan, please see my answer below. Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When setting up the printer under sysadm, I had to select "Remote to networked printer device" as the "Connection Type". You will now be able to disable the banner page when going through the rest of the setup options.

It's important to note that I have not been able to set banner page options using any of different "Connection Types".

Another work-around is to telnet into the printer and see if you can disable "Print Banner" on the printer. This also worked for me on some HP printers.

Hope this helps